# I need to execute an SQL query that pulls data from two tables and sorts it

Tags: sql, sorting

I'm trying to figure out how to form the query to extract the information I need as per below.

"List the ‘star number’ of all movie stars and how many films each has made. Sort the list from most prolific to least."

Tables are structured as per below:

- Star (starNumb, starName, brthPlce, starBorn, starDied)
- MovStar (mvNumb*, starNumb*)
- Movie (mvNumb, mvTitle, yrMde, mvType, crit, mpaa, noms, awrd, dirNumb*)
- Borrow (txNumb, mvNumb*, borDte, mmbNumb*)
- Member (mmbNumb, mmbName, mmbAddr, mmbCty, mmbSt, numRent, bonus, joinDate)
- Director (dirNumb, dirName, dirBorn, dirDied)

I have tried so far this which isn't working:

```
SELECT MOVIE.MVNUMB, STAR.STARNUMB,(COUNT)*
FROM MOVSTAR
GROUP BY MVNUMB
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MOVIE.MVNUMB, STAR.STARNUMB,(COUNT)* 
FROM MOVSTAR 
GROUP BY MVNUMB 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

you would need to add STAR.STARNUMB to the group by as follows

this would give you any record that totals more then 1 which is 2 or more.

```
SELECT MOVIE.MVNUMB, STAR.STARNUMB,(COUNT)* 
FROM MOVSTAR 
GROUP BY MVNUMB, STAR.STARNUMB 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

below is probably what you're looking for

```
Select Count(\*) as total, MovStar.StarNumb , Star.starName From Star
Inner Join (MovStar Inner Join Movie On Movie.mvNumb = movStar.mvNumb)
ON MovStar.StarNumb =Star.StarNumb Group By MovStar.StarNumb,
Star.starName order By Count(*) Desc
```

Comment: Im trying to calculate how any a movie star has been in a movie by using the StarNumb and mvNumb. StarNumb is the movie star number or unique number and mvNumb is the movie unique number. The records have multiple records showing for StarNumb for example there could be "1" two or three times associated with 3 different movie unique id numbers.